# How realistic is Kidd's job as a news reader?

Tags: realism, news-of-the-world

In the movie, *News of the world*, Kidd travels around and makes a living by reading the news to others.

I understand back then in the USA, people were likely to be illiterate. But did people really take up odd jobs like Kidd does in the movie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could parallel the job of 'town crier' from medieval Europe.
Not only can people not read, but the first person who can read, who also arrives with a newspaper (or any type of predecessor) not only knows what's going on in the outside world, but can be first to disseminate that information to any population they pass through.

Trying to make a profit from that is not an unlikely scenario.